# Animating a GradientBrush in UWP

Tags: xaml, animation, uwp, gradient

I want to animate a GradientBrush (LinearGradientBrush in my case) used by a control's fill property. I tried to change the gradient stops values (offset or color) in my storyboard but it doesn't seem to work. I target a grid's background for the example:

```
<Grid x:Name="LogoGrid" Height="512" Width="512">
    <Grid.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Name="LogoBackgroundBrush" StartPoint="0 0" EndPoint="1 1">
            <GradientStop x:Name="Stop0" Color="Transparent" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop x:Name="Stop1" Color="#80FFFFFF" Offset="0.5" />
            <GradientStop x:Name="Stop2" Color="Transparent" Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

And the storyboard:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="LoadingStoryBoard">
    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LogoGrid"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Background).(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
            RepeatBehavior="Forever" EnableDependentAnimation="True">
        <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="#40000000" KeyTime="0:0:1" />
        <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="#A0FFFFFF" KeyTime="0:0:2" />
    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you make sure to set `EnableDependentAnimation` to `true`?

You can look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40066702/734040) to another similar question for a complete example.

Comment: Yes, this property is enabled and I tried to animate the offset (DoubleAnimation) or the color (ColorAnimation). I have updated my question for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention how you start the storyboard. Anyway, I made it work by replacing `x:Key` with `x:Name` (otherwise I can't reference the storyboard from code).

#### XAML

```
<Grid x:Name="LogoGrid">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="LoadingStoryBoard">
            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                Storyboard.TargetName="LogoGrid"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Background).(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                EnableDependentAnimation="True">
                <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="#40000000" KeyTime="0:0:1" />
                <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="#A0FFFFFF" KeyTime="0:0:2" />
            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Name="LogoBackgroundBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
            <GradientStop x:Name="Stop0" Color="Transparent" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop x:Name="Stop1" Color="#80FFFFFF" Offset="0.5" />
            <GradientStop x:Name="Stop2" Color="Transparent" Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

### Code-behind

```
public sealed partial class MainPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += (sender, args) => LoadingStoryBoard.Begin();
    }
}
```

[Here is a complete demo project on GitHub](https://github.com/petterh/animated-gradient-brush-demo).

#### Edit

Tangetial: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40066702/3968276) shows how to access the storyboard through `x:Key` instead of my `x:Name`. The trick is to access the storyboard through `Resources`, e.g.:

```
((Storyboard)Resources["LoadingStoryboard"]).Begin();
```

Comment: I tried this solution but there is no color animation at all. My storyboard is well launched (i've tried with others animations), don't know where is the problem. The property "EnableDependentAnimation" was set to true.

Comment: @BertrandC: I put a minimal, self-contained project up on GitHub (see updated answer). If that doesn't work for you, I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will check this.