# Color Animation with ease

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-composition-api

I have been following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40065861/how-to-animated-grid-background-like-instagram-uwp-app) question to make a color animation.

I can create the animation and it runs fine until the animation gets started again. There is a moment where it feels that the animation has been started/stopped there for a moment. I want the animation to run smoothly so that it doesn't show any restarting effects in the colors. Is it possible to do that?

I am using the following code:

```
        <Storyboard x:Key="GradientAnimation"
                RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundBrush"
                SpeedRatio="0.3">
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Background).(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)"
            EnableDependentAnimation="True"
            BeginTime="-0:0:0.5">

            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="Black"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="Red"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="Black"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="Red"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="Black"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:5" Value="Red"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:6" Value="Black"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:7" Value="Red"/>

        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Background).(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
            EnableDependentAnimation="True">

            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="Red"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="Black"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="Red"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="Black"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="Red"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:5" Value="Black"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:6" Value="Red"/>
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:7" Value="Black"/>

        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

And I start this animation in code-behind:

```
((Storyboard)Resources["GradientAnimation"]).Begin();
```

Maybe there is some kind of 'easing' method that mixes up the start and stop of the animation so it appears as smooth as a long running animation. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think that you just need to finish at the same state that you begin. So it could be just Red -> Black -> Red. Doesn't it work?

Comment: What  do you mean by "gets started again"? Isn't it running forever? Do you manually stop and restart it?

Comment: It was running forever, yes, but it was not working as smooth as it needed to be because there was a 'gap' kinda thing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try `EasingColorKeyFrame` but the animation will never be smooth because it's running on the UI thread (i.e. `EnableDependentAnimation="True"`).

Here's some good and bad news. The good is that we now have new gradient brush API at the *Composition* layer level, which means it's fully animatable and running off the UI thread. So performance wise it's going to be much better than the current `Storyboard` solution. But it's only available in Windows 10 Insider Preview *16225* onward, which means it's not going to work for most of your current users except insiders.

However, I am still going to post this new solution here for future reference since there's no sample available on this topic yet.

Note I have added some extra sauce to the animation to make it more interesting. If you only want colors to be animated, feel free to move the `EndPoint` and `RotationAngleInDegrees` animations (I use the `EndPoint` animation to animate from a solid background color to a gradient at the startup of the app and `RotationAngleInDegrees` to rotate the gradient brush forever).

```
var compositor = Window.Current.Compositor;

// Initially, we set the end point to be (0,0) 'cause we want to animate it at start.
// If you don't want this behavior, simply set it to a different value within (1,1).
_gradientBrush = compositor.CreateLinearGradientBrush();
_gradientBrush.EndPoint = Vector2.Zero;

// Create gradient initial colors.
var gradientStop1 = compositor.CreateColorGradientStop();
gradientStop1.Offset = 0.0f;
gradientStop1.Color = GradientStop1StartColor;
var gradientStop2 = compositor.CreateColorGradientStop();
gradientStop2.Offset = 1.0f;
gradientStop2.Color = GradientStop2StartColor;
_gradientBrush.ColorStops.Add(gradientStop1);
_gradientBrush.ColorStops.Add(gradientStop2);

// Assign the gradient brush to the Root element's Visual.
_backgroundVisual = compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
_backgroundVisual.Brush = _gradientBrush;
ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(Root, _backgroundVisual);

// There are 3 animations going on here.
// First, we kick off an EndPoint offset animation to create an special entrance scene.
// Once it's finished, we then kick off TWO other animations simultaneously. 
// These TWO animations include a set of gradient stop color animations and
// a rotation animation that rotates the gradient brush.

var linearEase = compositor.CreateLinearEasingFunction();
var batch = compositor.CreateScopedBatch(CompositionBatchTypes.Animation);
batch.Completed += (s, e) =>
{
    StartGradientColorAnimations();
    StartGradientRotationAnimation();
};
var endPointOffsetAnimation = compositor.CreateVector2KeyFrameAnimation();
endPointOffsetAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
endPointOffsetAnimation.InsertKeyFrame(1.0f, Vector2.One);
_gradientBrush.StartAnimation(nameof(_gradientBrush.EndPoint), endPointOffsetAnimation);
batch.End();

void StartGradientColorAnimations()
{
    var color1Animation = compositor.CreateColorKeyFrameAnimation();
    color1Animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    color1Animation.IterationBehavior = AnimationIterationBehavior.Forever;
    color1Animation.Direction = AnimationDirection.Alternate;
    color1Animation.InsertKeyFrame(0.0f, GradientStop1StartColor, linearEase);
    color1Animation.InsertKeyFrame(0.5f, Color.FromArgb(255, 65, 88, 208), linearEase);
    color1Animation.InsertKeyFrame(1.0f, Color.FromArgb(255, 43, 210, 255), linearEase);
    gradientStop1.StartAnimation(nameof(gradientStop1.Color), color1Animation);

    var color2Animation = compositor.CreateColorKeyFrameAnimation();
    color2Animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    color2Animation.IterationBehavior = AnimationIterationBehavior.Forever;
    color2Animation.Direction = AnimationDirection.Alternate;
    color2Animation.InsertKeyFrame(0.0f, GradientStop2StartColor, linearEase);
    color1Animation.InsertKeyFrame(0.5f, Color.FromArgb(255, 200, 80, 192), linearEase);
    color2Animation.InsertKeyFrame(1.0f, Color.FromArgb(255, 43, 255, 136), linearEase);
    gradientStop2.StartAnimation(nameof(gradientStop2.Color), color2Animation);
}

void StartGradientRotationAnimation()
{
    var rotationAnimation = compositor.CreateScalarKeyFrameAnimation();
    rotationAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
    rotationAnimation.IterationBehavior = AnimationIterationBehavior.Forever;
    rotationAnimation.InsertKeyFrame(1.0f, 360.0f, linearEase);
    _gradientBrush.StartAnimation(nameof(_gradientBrush.RotationAngleInDegrees), rotationAnimation);
}
```

Here's a working [sample](https://github.com/JustinXinLiu/CompositionGradientColorAnimationRepo) and the following is how it looks like. :)

[image]

Comment: In my original question I only had to remove the `BeginTime` from the animation to make it smooth. But I really appreciate the effort.